# MVC Partial View Button Parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, button, routes, partial-views

I am trying to load a partial view once a button is clicked. Each button has it's own `commodityCode` value thus once clicked each will generate different results within the partial view.

My problem is that when a button is clicked the partial is the only thing being returned. Instead I want the partial to be loaded further down on the same page that the buttons are located. I can't use the `ajax.load()` Action approach because the variable which I'm passing as a parameter to the partial controller is taken from the `foreach(var item in Model.commodities)` code (as seen below) and I don't think there is a way to pass data from the model via a `foreach` loop then to `jQuery` then to the controller. Is there a way for me to specify where on the page the partial view should be loaded using C# rather than jQuery?

```
@foreach (var item in Model.commodities)
{
<tr>
   <td>
     <a class="arrow_button" href='@Url.Action("TliSelect", "Commodity", new { tariff = ViewBag.scac, commodityCode = item.commodityCode })'>
          <img style="width:15px; height:15px;" src="@Url.Content("/Content/images/expand-sm.png")" />
     </a>
   </td> // Continued...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your generating a link which will redirect to a new page. You need to use ajax to update the current page with the partial view returned by your `TliSelect()` method.

Change the link (button) to include a `data-` attribute for the `commodityCode` value so it can be stored and retrieved in your script

```
<a class="arrow_button" href="#" data-code="@item.commodityCode">....</a>
```

Then you script will be

```
var url = '@Url.Action("TliSelect", "Commodity")';
var tariff ='@ViewBag.scac';
var container = $(yourElement); // the element where you want to append the partial 
$('.arrow_button').click(function() {
    var code = $(this).data('code');
    container.load(url, { tariff: tariff, commodityCode: code });
});
```

or if you want to keep appending the partials, replace `.load()` with

```
$.get(url, { tariff: tariff, commodityCode: code }, function(html) {
    container.append(html);
});
```

Note this assumes your `TliSelect()` method returns a partial view.

Comment: Great solution. Thank you.